# How to install the latest node.js version on Linux VM?

Tags: node.js, npm

How can I install the latest node.js version on my Linux VM?
When I install it with`apt install nodejs npm`, it installs node.js v10.24.0, which doesn't support npm.

> npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v10.24.0
> npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
> npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
> npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9.
> npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/
> npm WARN ws@8.3.0 requires a peer of bufferutil@^4.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN ws@8.3.0 requires a peer of utf-8-validate@^5.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
> npm WARN bot@ No description
> npm WARN bot@ No repository field.
> npm WARN bot@ No license field.

Comment: install [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), then run `nvm install --lts`, simple. if you want a one-liner see https://github.com/deploy-script/node-js (though you should start a fresh else your need to uninstall the broken apt versions)

Answer (score -3):

you can install via package manager.